# Workaholic Formal/Informal

Tags: formal-language

Can I use the word "Workaholic" in formal writing?

for example:

> Workaholics may neglect their families and friends.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's quite an informal term, and I wouldn't expect to see if in formal writing.

What you *could* easily do, however, is phrase it as:

> So-called "workaholics" may neglect their families and friends.

It's a term that is widely used, and you're still referencing it. But because of its formality (or lack thereof), you're not including it as part of your wording.

Alternatively, be more descriptive:

> Those who work significantly longer hours may neglect their families and friends.

Comment: thanks a lot. apart from answering my question you also showed me a way of incorporating some unusual words in formal writings which i didn't know before. Can you elaborate on this more? another sentence coming to my mind: '' so-called ''fanatics'' of sports clubs''. can i use these kinds of sentences in formal writing?

Comment: I've heard that phrase format used many times in formal settings, yes. Perhaps the most common lately has been when referring to "the so-called Islamic State." The reasoning for this was that the group call themselves that, and others might too, but the media did not wish to use that language themselves and therefore give it credence.

Comment: I like this approach, but, what you would **really** want to do is use **either** the scare quotes **or** the _so-called_, but not both (in other words, not the so-called "scare quotes"). (See [Point #3 in this Writing Blog](https://www.dailywritingtips.com/3-erroneous-uses-of-scare-quotes/).)

Answer (score 2):

I think it’s an informal term.

There are simple and expressive alternatives you could use in formal settings.

> hard worker
>
> hard-working person
>
> (very/extremely) diligent worker
>
> industrious worker

They all have a positive connotation.

Comment: Whilst I agree that there are other more formal replacements, I don't think that any of those suggestions convey the intensity of "workaholic." One can be a diligent, industrious, hard worker and not be a workaholic.

Comment: I think the word **workaholic** generally comes with negative connotations; it certainly seems to do so in the example given in the question. I think all the suggestions in this answer are thereby disqualified.

Comment: Workoholic is somehow who lacks the life-work balance; hardworking doesn’t necessarily lack that.